# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCDemo/add] in DispatcherServlet with name

Tags: spring, maven

I am new to Spring MVC. I know there are many answers to my questions on stackoverflow but unfortunately none of them were helpful to solve mu issue. I am trying to implement simple mvc code but i am not able to identify my mistake: I am getting warning: "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCDemo/add] in DispatcherServlet with name 'sachin'"

here is index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="add">
    <input type="text" name="t1" /> <input type="text" name="t2" /> 
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sachin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sachin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My controller where I have used @Controller and @RequestMapping annotation

```
package com.sachin;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AddController {

@RequestMapping("/add")
public void add() {
    System.out.println("I am in AddController");
    }
}
```

My sachin-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">


<ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
<ctx:component-scan base-package="com.sachin.*"></ctx:component-scan>
</beans>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Could you please give as the DispatcherServlet code?

Comment: @M.Ismail its the part of org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet library. You want that?

Comment: try to change the url-pattern to /* instead of /